# How to change the compression method of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB version is 4.0, and I tried to install it for testing and change the compression method, but it did not work.
Here is my progress.

/etc/mongodb.conf

```
#originally
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

Here is what I added.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

engine:wiredTiger
    wiredTiger:                    # line 16
       engineConfig:
           cacheSizeGB: 1
           journalCompressor: none
           directoryForIndexes: false
       collectionConfig:
           blockCompressor: snappy
       indexConfig:
           prefixCompression: true
```

and

mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

I followed the official homepage, but I get the following error.

```
Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 16, column 15: illegal map value
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I'd like to know what is wrong.

Please let me know if you have any other options/ideas.
Please let me know how to verify that the option was applied.

Comment: I suspect you are just trying to get the config syntax correct, but FYI the compression options you've set are already the default for new collections (`snappy` for block compression and `true` for index prefix compression). Also note that the compression options in the `mongod` config file are only used as the default for new collections; this will not affect any compression on existing collections.

Comment: @Stennie I understood what you were talking about. If successfully applied, I will changed options block compression(none & zlib) and prefix(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setted WiredTiger twice

---

**Change that**

```
engine:wiredTiger
    wiredTiger:
```

---

**To**

```
engine:
    wiredTiger:
```